# DLL file version

Tags: delphi, dll, versioning

I have an application that uses a DLL to generate fastReports files.

When I need to make changes to the reports data structure I only change this DLL and distribute it to all user of the APP. How can I guarantee that all have the last version before they start?

How can I generate/Extract this information from the DLL file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This function will get the fileversion as string:

```
function FileVersionGet( const sgFileName : string ) : string;
var infoSize: DWORD;
var verBuf:   pointer;
var verSize:  UINT;
var wnd:      UINT;
var FixedFileInfo : PVSFixedFileInfo;
begin
  infoSize := GetFileVersioninfoSize(PChar(sgFileName), wnd);

  result := '';

  if infoSize <> 0 then
  begin
    GetMem(verBuf, infoSize);
    try
      if GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(sgFileName), wnd, infoSize, verBuf) then
      begin
        VerQueryValue(verBuf, '\', Pointer(FixedFileInfo), verSize);

        result := IntToStr(FixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionMS div $10000) + '.' +
                  IntToStr(FixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionMS and $0FFFF) + '.' +
                  IntToStr(FixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionLS div $10000) + '.' +
                  IntToStr(FixedFileInfo.dwFileVersionLS and $0FFFF);
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(verBuf);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The version info panel is disable for the .DLL Project. How can I enable it to activate and set version information?

Comment: @DRookie: Add {$R *.res} to the dll's project file.

Answer (score 6):

Get Dll version:

```
function GetDllVersion: string;  //Run in dll project
var
  fn: string;
begin
  fn := GetModuleName(HInstance); 
  Result := FileVersionGet(fn);  // use Matthias's function
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`SysUtils.GetFileVersion()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.GetFileVersion)

Getting file version requires setting file version *in advance*.

Comment: Version Information should be included into project under `Project/Options`

Comment: The version info panel is disable for the .DLL Project. How can I enable it to activate and set version information?

Answer (score 0):

JCL have JclFileVersion. Two or three lines and you are done.